# Get ServiceLocator in Constructor of Controller Class

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I am building a module in [zend-framework2](/questions/tagged/zend-framework2). I want to access `ServiceLocator` in constructor of Controller class.

```
public function __construct() {
    var_dump($this->getServiceLocator()->get('Config'));
}
```

But it gives following error.

> Call to a member function get() on a non-object

When I tried to get this in Action, It works perfect -

```
public function inAction() {
    $sm = $this->getServiceLocator();
    $config = $sm->get('Config');
}
```

What is the correct way to get `ServiceLocator` in constructor?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the time of the construction of a class, the dependency of the `ServiceLocator` is not yet injected. This happens after that through initializers.

The workflow is like that:

```
- controller called "My\Controller\FooController"
- resolve string to classname
- $ctrl = new FooController(); // This is where __construct() is called
if $ctrl instanceof AbstractActionController
    $ctrl->setServiceLocator($serviceLocator);
endif
- return $ctrl;
```

The easiest workaround is to write yourself a lazy getter function inside your controller:

```
protected $config;

public function getConfig() {
    if (null === $this->config) {
        $this->config = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('config');
    }
    return $this->config;
}
```

This approach will work and you'll be happy. However you should know that this isn't actually best practice, since you call a dependency from another dependency. A better way would be to actually inject the config into your controller.

```
public function __construct(array $config) {
    $this->config = $config;
}
```

And the instead of an `invokable` you write a `factory`. This is done at best in the `getControllerConfig()` function of your `Module`-Class

```
public function getControllerConfig() {
    return array(
        'factories' => array(
            'My\Controller\FooController' => function($cpm) {
                $sl = $cpm->getServiceLocator();
                return new FooController(
                    $sl->get('config')
                );
            }
        )
    );
}
```

And then the config will be injected into your controller and it will also be available inside your `__construct()` in case you wanna cut out specific parts of the whole config.

Comment: Thanks @Sam for such a nice reply. I tried the second solution but I get following error.  
    
*Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to Auth\Controller\AuthController::__construct() must be of the type array, none given, ...*

Comment: @AshwiniAgarwal Try to var_dump($sl->get('config')); and see if it returns something (do that outside of the new FooController()) call and save it into a variable first - this code should work - did u remove your contrller alias from the invokables array?

Comment: @Sam.. Do I need to do some other configuration updates, Because it's not printing anything from there. *(I have tried putting `echo 'test';` just before `new FooController()`, And it prints nothing.)*

Comment: echo "test"; die(); - that'll do something ;)

Comment: @Sam.. Output is still same.

Comment: ***And the instead of an invokable you write a factory.*** Do I need to remove invokables?

Comment: yes, it's **instead**. If you leave the invokable, only the invokable will be called and no factory-processing happens ;)

Comment: A little bit more background with an explanation similar to this answer: https://juriansluiman.nl/article/139/zf2-why-a-service-is-not-available-in-your-constructor

Comment: @Sam.. In addition, is it also possible to pass `MvcEvent` using this method?

Comment: @AshwiniAgarwal iirc you can't getch the mvcevent frmo the servicemanager, therefore no. And i wonder what the use-case would be, sounds a bit impractical to me

Comment: @Sam.. I am mixing up all the things.. :O